# How to click on hidden element in protractor?

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, selenium-webdriver, protractor

I have an element which is visible only when I hover over it.

I've written following code to hove over the panel so that the element is visible.

```
ptor.actions().
            mouseMove(ptor.findElement(protractor.By.xpath('//*[@id="productapp"]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div[4]/table/thead/tr/th[2]'))).
            perform();
        ptor.element.all(by.tagName('i')).then(function(elm){
            elm[0].click();
        });
```

Now I tried to click on it, but it says -
    ElementNotVisibleError: element not visible
error in protractor.

Basic scenario is, I want to hover over a panel and then click on the hidden element, because the element is not visible until it is hovered over.

Comment: Can't post my answer, don't have reputation to do it. Anyways found the answer. Guys have the answer, following code worked for me -
`ptor.actions().
                mouseMove(ptor.findElement(protractor.By.xpath('//*[@id="productapp"]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div[4]/table/thead/tr/th[2]'))).
                perform();
            ptor.element.all(by.css('i.ng-scope.tea-ic-sorting')).then(function(elm){
                elm[0].click();
            });`

Comment: I voted up your question, I think you'll be able to set this as an answer now. I'm surprised there were no duplicate on StackOverflow. This is a recurrent issue. ;) Good luck!

Comment: Thanks. I will set this as an answer now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Following code worked for me.

```
  ptor.actions().
    mouseMove(ptor.findElement(protractor.By.xpath('//*@id="productapp"]/div/div/di‌​v[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div[4]/table/thead/tr/th[2]'))).perform();

   ptor.element.all(by.css('i.ng-scope.tea-ic-sorting')).then(function(elm){
       elm[0].click();
    });
```

Comment: I tried this but still got `"Element is not currently visible and may not be manipulated"`

Comment: It's hoverable. Works in Chrome and FireFox but am trying to force the click in PhantomJS, which really isn't happy about the hidden element. And Safari has a bug with mouse functions as well - https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=4136

Comment: Can't thank you enough for this, I have been going down the wrong path trying to get this click to execute for over 24 hours now and this hover method worked perfectly the first time. Thank you!

Answer (score 7):

Sometimes, there are cases when you intentionally want to click a hidden element.

---

One option would be to click *via javascript*:

```
var elm = element(by.id("myid"));
browser.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", elm.getWebElement());
```

See also: [WebDriver click() vs JavaScript click()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34562061/webdriver-click-vs-javascript-click)

---

Another, to *make an element visible* and click it. Now, this depends on how the element was hidden - with a `style.block` or `style.visibility` or with the `ng-hide` etc. Sample solution where we set the element's `visibility` to `visible` and the `display` to `block`:

```
var elm = element(by.id("myid"));
browser.executeScript(function (arguments) {
    arguments[0].style.visibility = 'visible'; 
    arguments[0].style.display = 'block';
}, elm.getWebElement());
```

Comment: The first option worked fine. I had some tests that were already working, but some colleagues changed the styles and for some strange reason my code could no longer click on the checkboxes, even when they were fully visible. Thanks!

Comment: If it were set up with type="hidden", would there be an executeScript that could override that?

Comment: @JeremyKahan you, you can do `arguments[0].setAttribute('type', 'text');`

Comment: so I tried, but I got arguments[0] is undefined even after a line in between that did a browser.wait on EC.presenceOf(elm)

Comment: Option 1 does not give the error about no arguments you get with option 2 nor the problem with protractor's click about interacting with something not visible, but also does not give the result of populating the underlying menu options that an actual click does in a real life session.

Comment: and after the executescript click and a browser.sleep, the element still does not have focus, and         browser.actions().sendKeys(" ", protractor.Key.DOWNARROW).perform();
do not get through to it.

Comment: terrible hack: bypassed the whole issue by taking the element and saying:             browser.executeScript("arguments[0].setAttribute('value','"+t+"');", elm.getWebElement()); 
where t was a string holding the desired value. Note I am just trying to automate a repeated task, not to test the product, so anything that would get past this was good. Thanks for the help @alecxe