# How can i change the visibility of a invisible elements (shown in appium inspector) to true in protractor?

Tags: angularjs, protractor, visibility, appium, end-to-end

I 'm testing an Angular JS site with protractor and Appium, [image: Recorder details]. The click into the login button isn't working as i have mentionned here [The problem with click()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36871071/click-function-isnt-working-in-protractor-scripts).

- Is it possible that because `visible = false` from inspector details?
- In that case how can i change the visibility of a button into `true` ?
- I get true with that code :

`loginbutton.isDisplayed().then(function(result){
                   console.log(result);
           });`

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22265040/how-to-click-on-hidden-element-in-protractor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was not the origin problem that the click into login button isn't done as i have expected, i solved it by changing the way when clicking into a button in protractor by this way :

`browser.actions().mouseMove(loginButton).click().perform();`

Here the [Origin of the problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36871071/click-function-isnt-working-in-protractor-scripts).

Hope that this help you.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can change any attributes using native Javascript. Protractor can run JavaScript in context of some element. Take a look [here](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/faq.md#how-can-i-interact-directly-with-the-javascript-running-in-my-app).

So the answer probably would be like this:

```
browser
.executeScript("document.querySelector(<yourElementSelectionPath>).setAttribute('visible', 'true')");
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i will try it :)  but instead of document what shall i put ?

Comment: sorry. you need to put the argument into quotes. everything should work then. Try now.

Comment: try to query something simple first. like `document.querySelector("body")` and then print it (add `.then(function(data){console.log(data);})`)

Comment: DOM exception 12  isn't there anymore

Comment: try to find your element in browser console using this `document.querySelector` syntax, maybe you don't find it properly.

Comment: The problem may be in html code i have <md-button type="submit" class="md-raised login-button" ng-disabled="clicked" translate="login.LOGIN">Login </md-button> </section> 
and in appium visible=false, shall i use clicked instead?
i'm sure about the elt location, because i use it before of the button

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110827/discussion-between-zmii-and-emna).